# OpenCL get_global_id probably return

Tags: c++, kernel, range, opencl

I have suspiciton of multiple calls of OpenCL kernel with same `get_global_id(0)` return value.

calling from host:

```
err = commandQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(my_kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(1024), cl::NDRange(256), NULL, NULL);
```

and my kernel:

```
typedef struct { float x, y; } Point3;

__kernel void update_position (
    __global Point3* pts,
    __global Point3* speed,
    const unsigned int count,
    const float t)
{ 
    unsigned long i = get_global_id(0);
    if (i < count) { 
        pts[i].x += speed[i].x * t;
        pts[i].y += speed[i].y * t;
    }
}
```

What I want is to update every item of 1024 `pts` once and only once. The problem is that running program multiple times I get various non-valid results. I guess `get_global_id(0)` does NOT return a unique number between 0 and 1023 (inclusive) so sometimes is this body of kernel executed more than once.

Unfortunatelly official web API of Khronos is being down and I haven't found any suitable answer/solution.

Should I use other function to determine what core/thread the code runs on? Or are `NDRange`s called wrong?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your kernel looks fine, and `get_global_id(0)` *does* do exactly what you want. Can you give us some more information about how you are creating/initialising the buffers/arguments?

Comment: Possible problems, the argument `count`, and how you initialize `pts`.